# Try/except runs except even though it's not supposed to

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have pieced together a web crawler that looks for alternative xpaths to text content on a webpage. In the example below, it is supposed to look for two alternative xpaths, and depending on which one is available, it will then turn that into the variable `issuer`.

```
try:
    xpath_issuer = ".//*[@id='dv_PRE88f496c28ad6488895f1ffc383fae8bd_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"
    find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
    issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
try:
    xpath_issuer = ".//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"
    find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
    issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

However I will in reality be looking for many xpaths, not just these two. I have tried to define `class Work():` as a way of shortening the expression so I don't have to repeat everything so much.

```
def crawl(x):
#Looks for variable Name here, omitted
    list_xpath_issuer = [".//*[@id='dv_PRE88f496c28ad6488895f1ffc383fae8bd_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]", ".//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"]
    class Work():
        def __init__(self):
            y = self.getIssuer()
            print(y)

        def getIssuer(self):
            for i in range(len(list_xpath_issuer)):
                xpath_issuer = list_xpath_issuer[i]
                try:
                    find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
                    issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group().encode("utf-8")
                    print "Issuer: %s" % issuer
                    return "Xpath is %s" % xpath_issuer
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    print "This is an exception"
                    pass
    Work()
    return pd.Series([isin, instrument_name, issuer])
df[["Name", "Issuer"]] = df["ISIN"].apply(crawl)
```

The problem is that for some reason, in the end `issuer` turns up empty with this error:

> NameError: global name 'issuer' is not defined

It does find one of the xpaths as intended and passes that on to `issuer` as long as it is working in the `try` phase, but for some reason it also runs the `except` phase and that negates the value in `issuer`. Any ideas why?

Edit: Traceback

```
This is an exception
Issuer: Boost Issuer Plc
Xpath is .//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xetra_lookup16.py", line 211, in <module>
    df[["Name", "Symbol", "Issuer"]] = df["ISIN"].apply(crawl)
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2053, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1064, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:58519)
  File "xetra_lookup16.py", line 208, in crawl
    return pd.Series([isin, instrument_name, issuer])
NameError: global name 'issuer' is not defined
```

Comment: How do you know the ```except``` suite is executing?  Add a print statement to be sure.  Also, you should post the complete Traceback.

Comment: @wwii I have done that, I added the row `print "this is an exception"`. I have edited the question with the traceback.

Comment: This traceback adds nothing useful to the problem. It looks like the exception is thrown before variable `issuer` is assigned. More useful would be traceback from this exception. So remove `pass` keyword from first two try-catch blocks and print the traceback in those places

Comment: Are you even calling `getIssuer()`?

Comment: You need to assign the return value of ```Work()``` to a name,  ```issuer```. Or, ```w= Work()``` then ```issuer = w.y```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The except suites are working *just fine*.

The problem lies outside of your exception handling. You are trying to use the name `issuer` in your `crawl` function, but it is never set there.

`issuer` is a *local variable* in `crawl`, and not the same variable used in the `Work.getIssuer()` method. The two are entirely unrelated. Setting one does not make the other appear.

When you create an instance of `Work()`, it may *print* the result, but nothing is actually passed on to the caller. I'm not sure why you are using a class here at all; you could just as well just inline that method:

```
def crawl(x):
#Looks for variable Name here, omitted
    list_xpath_issuer = [
        ".//*[@id='dv_PRE88f496c28ad6488895f1ffc383fae8bd_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]",
        ".//*[@id='dv_PRE00e883469a264528b20fbbc31b0da4a2_list_list']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a"
    ]

    issuer = None
    for xpath_issuer in list_xpath_issuer:
        try:
            find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
            issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group().encode("utf-8")
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
    return pd.Series([isin, instrument_name, issuer])
```